# Eloquent Javascript - ch4 - arraytoList - Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I went thru all the solutions related to this particular exercise in Eloquent Javascript but nothing gives solution to my problem.

You can see the [`arrayToList function here`](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.3)

My question is how to write a program by looping from start to end rather than end to start.

Here is my solution:

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
  var entry = { value: null, rest: null}
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(entry.value == null) 
      entry.value = arr[i]
    else{ 
      entry.rest = arrayToList([arr[i]])
        }
  }
  return entry
}

console.log(arrayToList([10,20]));
```

This is coming fine.

```
Input - console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
output - { value: 10, rest: { value: 20, rest: null } }
```

But the below one giving issue

```
Input - console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]));
Actual output - { value: 10, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } }

Expected output - { value: 10,
  rest: { value: 20, rest: { value: 30, rest: null } } }
```

I don't know how to call recursively so that even if there more than 2 elements in array it still able to create list structure

Comment: simplest solution that I could come up for this problem:function arrayToList5(arr) {
    var obj = {value: null, rest: null}
    if(arr.length === 0){
        return null
    }
    obj.value = arr[0]
    obj.rest = arrayToList5(arr.slice(1))
    
    return obj 

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your link with an empty array the function returns null and seems that only unnamed array will be passed in this exercice so i dont care about original array (will be emtpy after function execution).

```js
function arrayToList(arr, curr = null){
  switch(curr = arr.shift()){
    case undefined:
      return null
      break
    default:
      return {value: curr, rest: arrayToList(arr)}
  }
}

let arr = [10,20,30,0,50]
console.log(arrayToList(arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top: 0; max-height: none!important;}
```

Comment: If the array contains a falsy value like `0`, this would fail.

Comment: It also destroys the array passed to it.

Comment: You are genius. First time I came across code where you assign value within if condition. I don't know how to think recursively like you. My thinking is always like assign initial value, see whether any looping required or condition check, and then only if same pattern repeats I think about recursive. But you directly jumped into it. How to think like that?

Comment: Edited with a solution that handles 0 values... Nothing special just i think to recursion when i see a 'repetitive nested structure'. Anyway my solution its a little bit rude ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You need to pass the rest of the array in the recursive call, e.g.

```js
// Return object like {"value": 10, "rest": {"value": 20, "rest": null}}

function arrayToList0(arr) {
  var entry = {};
  // Check if there are any members in arr
  if (arr.length) {
    // If there are, add the value
    entry.value = arr[0];
  }
  
  // If there are more entries, add them
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    // Call recursively without first element
    entry.rest = arrayToList(arr.slice(1));
    
  // Otherwise, add null
  } else {
    entry.rest = null;
  }
  return entry;
}

console.log(arrayToList([1,2,3]));
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
  var entry = arr.length? {value:arr[0]} : {};
  entry.rest = arr.length > 1? arrayToList(arr.slice(1)) : null;
  return entry;
}
```

You don't say what to do with sparse arrays, the above expects contiguous arrays with no missing elements. For sparse arrays, you'll end up with lots of `value: undefined` in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this approach is an improvement over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46540605/1541563), as an empty array correctly returns an object with the properties `value` and `rest`, falsy values in the array don't cause early exit, and the array is not mutated by passing it to the function. It uses simple top-down recursion to generate the nested list.

```js
function arrayToList (array, entry = { value: null, rest: null }) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return entry
  }

  return {
    value: array[0],
    rest: arrayToList(array.slice(1), null)
  }
}

console.log(arrayToList([])) // empty
console.log(arrayToList([10, 0, 20])) // falsy
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not need to use recursion

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  var re = {rest: null};
  for (var i = 0, c = re; i < array.length; i++) {
    c = c.rest = {value: array[i], rest: null};
  }
  return re.rest;
}
```

If you are required to use recursive algorithm, the following is my recommended solution.

Use an index parameter, it would be more efficient than other answers which use recursive algorithm.

No new array was created, and no changes to the original array.

```js
function arrayToList(arr, i) {
  return (i = i || 0) < arr.length ? {value: arr[i], rest: arrayToList(arr,i+1)} : null;
}
```

If you don't like the extra parameter, wrap it within another function.
Maybe looks like:

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
  return (function inner(r, i) {
    return i < r.length ? {value: r[i], rest: inner(r,i+1)} : null;
  })(arr, 0);
}
```

Comment: Provably, you never *need* recursion.  But to create a recursive data structure such as this, its simplicity is hard to beat, e.g. `const arrayToList = (xs) => xs .length == 0 ? null : {value: xs [0], rest: arrayToList (xs .slice (1))}`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet  `slice` method will create new array instance

Comment: Yes it will.  There's often a trade-off between simplicity and speed.  I choose simplicity first and only optimize if there's a provable reason to do so.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
      var entry = { value: null, rest: null };
      
      for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        
        entry = { value: array[i], rest: entry };
      }
      
      return entry;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10,20,30]));
```

Comment: Since you're using a loop you don't need recursion as this defeats its benefits.

Comment: Output of your code is incorrect: {"value":50,"rest":{"value":40,"rest":{"value":30,"rest":{"value":20,"rest":{"value":10,"rest":{"value":null,"rest":null}}}}}}

Comment: It's in the reverse order

Comment: It's a wrong answer which give wrong result.